# Solving a system of ODEs in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-deployment

this is my first time posting, so if you need anymore info or I havn't done something correct please let me know!

I want to plot a system of **ODES**, which would be no problem as I would do the following;

```
F=@(t,x) [
.the RHS of my first order ODES.
];


[t x]=ode45(F,[Range], [Initial conditions]);
```

Where a vector would be created containing x'(1), x'(2),... where x(1), x(2) would be the time dependant variable.

However my system is a little more complicated. I have 6 differential equations which are made up of equations that include differential equations and the time dependant variables. For example, the RHS of my ODES are something like 
2*x(2)*x'(1)*f(a)

Where f(a) could be another function based on constants, a.

I have set up my code in the following order;

Constants, then equations of the form f(a), then my differential equations followed by the ode45 solver and the plot commands. However I am getting several errors "Undefined function or variable" as early equations depend on variables/equations that are not defined until later.

Thank you ever so much for you help :)

As suggested, here an example of the type of my code;

```
`%Constants
a=34
b=31
c=20
%Equations
A=b*cos(2*pi)
B=a*EQ1
C=c*x(2)
%DifferentialEquations
EQ1=x(1)*A
EQ2=(EQ3-EQ1)*(B-C)
EQ3=x(2)*x(3)
F=@(t,x) [EQ1;EQ2;EQ3;];[t x]=ode45(F,[0 10], [0 0 0 ]);
```

Provides the error.
Produces the undefined function or variable 'DEQ1A'.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a snippet of the code you have tried that is not working, plus the real error messages that show what is going wrong (in context). Plus, be sure to use the {} button on the editor when entering code to ensure it is formatted correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Jodag however the main issue remains

Comment: Could you update the problem with actual MATLAB code that reproduces the error you are encountering? I believe I've been able to correctly define `F` based on the equations you gave and `ode45` didn't return any errors.

Comment: @Jodag. When I enter the code as above I get the error of undefined variable EQ1

Comment: @Jodag, If you copy/paste the code does it work for you?

Comment: @ODAmatuer Yes, it seems you are having issues defining `F`. I posted an answer that should help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment you are trying to use a variable before it is defined. In MATLAB you need to define your variables and functions before you use them. Because the equations are functions of each other you can use [anonymous functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to define `F`.

Example:

```
a=34;
b=31;
c=20;
A = b*cos(2*pi);
EQ1 = @(x) x(1)*A;
B = @(x) a*EQ1(x);
C = @(x) c*x(2);
EQ3 = @(x) x(2)*x(3);
EQ2 = @(x) (EQ3(x) - EQ1(x))*(B(x)-C(x));
F = @(t,x) [EQ1(x);EQ2(x);EQ3(x)];
[t,x] = ode45(F,[0 10], [0 0 0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will try this out.

Comment: It's worth noting that the derivatives of all your functions (`EQ1`,`EQ2`,`EQ3`) are constant with respect to `t` and they are all 0 for the initial condition of `[0 0 0]` which means no change over time.

Comment: Thanks, I am dealing with a very, very large file so not all will be 0; these were just examples to display the problem which you have solved. In short, do I add at @(x) to functions that are yet defined, and rename A and B to A(x) and B(x)?

Comment: Sort of. But the order certainly matters. For example if you try to define `B` before `EQ1` then you will have an error.